# authClient.login returning error with "Unauthorized request origin"

Tags: firebase

This just started happening within the past few days, and my code hasn't changed.  Have I made a mistake, or is this new?

It seems like it's implying there's a rule I should be adding to my security rules in firebase forge to allow access from the domain I'm working on (in this case localhost), but I don't know where to find that documentation.

Can anyone help?  How do I get past this error?

Comment: I discovered after much experimentation that I was receiving this error because the ScriptSafe plugin for Chrome was doing something to cause it. Once I turned that off, it worked as expected.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With the release of Firebase Simple Login, which contains a number of OAuth-based authentication methods (Facebook, Twitter, GitHub, etc.), we included the idea of 'Authorized Origins'. Without this restriction, malicious sites could pretend to be your application and attempt to access your users' Facebook, Twitter, etc. data on your behalf.

By restricting the domains for these requests to ones that you control and have verified, we can protect your users' data.

To fix this error, log into Firebase Forge (by dropping your Firebase URL into your browser), and navigate to the 'Auth' panel on the left. You can configure multiple application domains here, comma-delimited. If you're interested in testing locally, set `127.0.0.1` in your application domain configuration, and ensure that you're accessing pages via `http://127.0.0.1/...`, rather than `http://localhost/...`. I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, the auth panel was what I was looking for.  FWIW, I was able to create and authenticate users using the email/password login system up to this point without having any authorized origins.

Comment: dang comma! I had my entry in there, but it wouldn't enter the data and save until I hit comma…

Comment: @RobDiMarco Is it possible to make use of the Twitter API (e.g. through jQuery AJAX calls to get latest timeline tweets) after a user had authenticated through Firebase? I see that the `user` object that is returned after authenticating has some limited information.

Comment: @GFoley83 We return the OAuth token and corresponding OAuth secret in the response payload, so you can use those to authenticate and make requests against the Twitter API. However, this is not built-in to Firebase Simple Login. If there's specific, commonly-used items you'd like to see added to the response payload, let us know! Reach out to us at support@firebase.com.

Comment: Rather frustratingly, you MUST enter a comma. If you simply tab out of the textbox you'll see a toast saying it's saved, but it's not applied!