# authClient.login problems

Tags: firebase

I'm having a similar problem as was discussed in this question: 
[authClient.login returning error with "Unauthorized request origin"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14276815/authclient-login-returning-error-with-unauthorized-request-origin?rq=1)

I can't find anything on the firebase site that directly addresses this problem so I have 2 questions about the "unauthorized request origin":

1.) If I'm testing my program through my own computer (as in, it's just a file on my computer), what exactly am I supposed to add to the Auth panel? I tried following the advice offered in the link above but no luck.

2.) My eventual plan is to create an app using firebase and it's login system. Is this going to be a problem for when users try to login? Is there going to be something that I need to allow so that any user will be allowed to login to the system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the release of Firebase Simple Login, which contains a number of OAuth-based authentication methods (Facebook, Twitter, GitHub, etc.), we included the idea of 'Authorized Origins'. Without this restriction, malicious sites could pretend to be your application and attempt to access your users' Facebook, Twitter, etc. data on your behalf.

By restricting the domains for these requests to ones that you control and have verified, we can protect your users' data. Once you have configured your application domains, your users will be able to log in seamlessly and securely from the domains you defined.

To fix this error, log into Firebase Forge (by entering your Firebase URL into your browser), and navigate to the 'Auth' panel on the left.

- For testing locally, you'll need to run at least a barebones webserver on your machine, rather than loading your test files via `file://`. The easiest way to run a barebones server on your local machine is to `cd` to the directory of your files and run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`, which will allow you to access your content via `http://127.0.0.1:8000/...`.
- For your users, configure the domains that you'll be using to host your application. This can be any number of specific subdomains (such as `a.b.www.domain.com`) or high-level domains which will act as a wildcard (`domain.com` will allow requests from `*.domain.com`).

You can configure multiple application domains or IPs here, comma-delimited.

See https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-overview.html for additional documentation about application configuration for Simple Login.

I hope that helps! Feel free to ping me directly if you have further questions.

Comment: the `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` tip is very handy! Thanks!

Comment: What about Phonegap? How can we handle the file://* issue?

Comment: The python tip is still relevant. All my login code was working perfectly on my file:/// files until today (28 Aug 2016) where everything still worked except logging in. Where it gave this error: 
`Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'file://' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404`

I ran the python local server and it works now. Still mad at why it suddenly stopped working though.