# Firebase Google Authentication Hangs in Chrome Extension

Tags: authentication, google-chrome-extension, firebase

I'm trying to implement Firebase's Google authentication in the popup window of a chrome extension. The regular email/password authentication works fine, but when I try with Google auth, it hangs on a grey screen whose URL begins with "https://auth.firebase.com/auth/google/callback?state=..."

Any idea what the issue is?

Comment: Can you obtai the error that is thrown and share that here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that [Firebase Simple Login](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-overview.html) is a separate service built on top of [Firebase Authentication](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/authentication.html), intended to simplify authenticating users and generating Firebase Auth. Tokens for use in [Security Rules](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/security-rules.html).

At the time of this writing, authenticating via pop-up in a browser extension is unsupported via Firebase Simple Login, due to the constraints around authenticating origins in OAuth. In order to use Firebase Simple Login for this task, the login will have to take place on a hosted domain.

See [Firebase Authentication in a Chrome Extension Background Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14925179/firebase-authentication-in-a-chrome-extension-background-page) for related information and answer.

Comment: For some reason I am still able to authenticate successfully using Simple Login, through my pop up window.

Comment: @harveyxia Can you clarify what you mean? I thought that you said that the authentication wasn't working?

Comment: The regular email/password authentication works fine.

But when I try with Google auth, it hangs on a grey screen whose URL begins with "https://auth.firebase.com/auth/google/callback?state=..."

Comment: @harveyxia Email / password authentication works in the Chrome extension since it is now OAuth, and is not relying on cookies / redirects / etc. to authenticate the user. Only the OAuth-based providers (Facebook, Google, GitHub, Twitter, etc.) have this restriction around application origin, since they don't require you to login again to "login to an app".