# OAuth 2.0 and Chrome extensions

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-extension, oauth, oauth-2.0, firebase

I'm using angularfire/firebase to authenticate with various OAuth 2.0 providers (github, google, facebook, twitter) from a chrome extension. They all return the same error: **Authentication failed: Error: The user cancelled authentication.(…)**

Looking for a way that the extension can capture the token generated from firebase's $auth function.

Thanks!

Comment: Without the relevant code (isn't it a requirement for such questions?) I can only suggest whitelisting all domains used for OAuth redirects in manifest.json's [CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy) and/or ["permissions"](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions). Take a look at your background page console, try debugging the code, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to do the same thing as you and I am getting the same error.

From this page: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-storing

Note: Browser popups and redirects are not available on all platforms or browser environments. Popups are not available in Chrome for iOS, iOS Preview Panes, or local, file:// URLs. Redirects are not available in PhoneGap / Cordova, or local, file:// URLs. Therefore, it is recommended that you use a combination of both authentication methods to cover all environments:

Have you tried using the redirect method?

Comment: Thanks flan. Good info! I'll look into having the various auth method fallbacks. Yes, I think I tried both methods but will double check again. My extension is a drop down so the pop-up / redirect just might not be viable.

Comment: The more I have looked into it the less I think it is possible after all - see here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14925179/firebase-authentication-in-a-chrome-extension-background-page) and here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23477605/firebase-google-authentication-hangs-in-chrome-extension) both answered by a firebase engineer